# dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu in acer aspire e1-572

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, uefi

how to make dual boot windows 8 and UBUNTU in ACER ASPIRE E1-572.Please help me ...I have usb bootable with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.4.9 and when try to install it in system ,it halts..
plz help me to resolve it.

Comment: Besure to turn off secure boot, fast boot and boot flash drive in UEFI mode.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [Ubuntu's wiki on UEFI issues.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- [My page on installing Linux on EFI-based computers.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

If neither of these helps, you'll need to post more details. Most importantly, [what's your Windows boot mode?](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html) (I'm assuming EFI because you're using Windows 8, but that's not really a 100% safe assumption. If you're *not* booting Windows in EFI mode, you should also ignore my first two links.) Also, describe how it's failing in more detail -- how far can you get, what (if any) error messages do you see, etc. Unfortunately, "it halts" describes dozens, if not hundreds, of problems, each with its own solution.